# How is it that these squares only translate once instead of multiple times within the setInterval?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```js
var initialCircle;
var i;
var randomXPos;
var randomYPos;
var colorArray;
var interval01;
var circleNodeList;
var circleNodeListIndividual;
var xDirection = 5;
var yDirection = 5;
var dX = xDirection + 5;
var dY = yDirection + 5;
colorArray = [
  'aliceblue', 'lavender', 'powderblue', 'lightblue', 'lightskyblue', 'skyblue', 'deepskyblue', 'lightsteelblue', 'dodgerblue', 'cornflowerblue', 'steelblue', 'cadetblue', 'mediumslateblue', 'slateblue', 'darkslateblue', 'royalblue', 'blue', 'mediumblue', 'darkblue', 'navy', 'midnightblue', 'blueviolet', 'indigo'
];
var randomColor;




function startBouncingHoverCircles() {
  interval01 = setInterval(function() {
    randomXPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 380) + 31;
    randomYPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 235) + 31;
    randomColor = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];
    initialCircle = document.createElement('div');
    document.querySelector("#container").appendChild(initialCircle);
    initialCircle.className = "aces";
    initialCircle.style = 'height:30px;width:30px;border-radius:50%;box-sizing:border-box;position:absolute;border:3px solid green;background-color:' + randomColor;
    initialCircle.style.top = randomYPos + 'px';
    initialCircle.style.left = randomXPos + 'px';
  }, 1);
  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(interval01);
    movement()
  }, 100)
}

function movement() {
  setInterval(function() {
    circleNodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".aces");
    for (i = 0; i < circleNodeList.length; i++) {
      circleNodeListIndividual = circleNodeList[i];
      circleNodeListIndividual.style.transition = "transform 1s";
      circleNodeListIndividual.style.transform = 'translate(' + dX + 'px' + ',' + dY + 'px' + ')'
    }
  }, 1500)
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/randomcolor/0.6.1/randomColor.min.js" integrity="sha512-vPeZ7JCboHcfpqSx5ZD+/jpEhS4JpXxfz9orSvAPPj0EKUVShU2tgy7XkU+oujBJKnWmu4hU7r9MMQNWPfXsYw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    #container {
      width: 450px;
      height: 300px;
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button onClick="startBouncingHoverCircles()">Start</button>
  <div id="container"></div>

  <script src="../Js/bouncingHoverCircles.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to have these balls bounce off the walls and reverse direction when they hit a wall. the first step is setting up an interval for them to continue to animate across the screen. I am trying to accomplish this without the implementation of a canvas. Any help as to why the interval only runs one time would be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setInterval runs OK.

The problem is that you always put the circles again at the same point. When you do `'translate(' + dX + 'px' + ',' + dY + 'px' + ')'` - The `dX` and `dY` are not added to the current location of the circle. They are used as the new location (which always stays 10px.)

2 options for solution:

1. Increase `dX` and `dY` every time you call `movement()`.
2. Probably better solution: When you set the `transform` property in your element - Sum the current location with the `dX` and `dY`. **Code to do that:**

   Add the next variable before you set the `transform` in the movement function:

   ```
   const matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(circleNodeListIndividual.style.transform);
   ```

   then use it in setting the `transform`:

   ```
   circleNodeListIndividual.style.transform = 'translate(' + (matrix.m41 + dX) + 'px' + ',' + (matrix.m42 + dY) + 'px' + ')'
   ```

Comment: indeed.. right above the line `circleNodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".aces");` i put `dX+=5; dY+=5` and it transformed every time.. nice catch ravid